# How to add a Column to an empty DataFrame in Julia

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I want to append a vector as a column to an empty `DataFrame`. Suppose I have defined an empty `DataFrame` like this:

```
import DataFrames
dataframe = DataFrames.DataFrame()
```

Then I want to append this vector as a column to the `dataframe`:

```
vec = [1,2,3]
```

I tried `push!(dataframe , vec)`, but I got this error:

```
DimensionMismatch("Length of `row` does not match `DataFrame` column count.")

Stacktrace:
  [1] push!(df::DataFrames.DataFrame, row::Vector{Int64}; promote::Bool)
    @ DataFrames C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\DataFrames\BM4OQ\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:1691
  [2] push!(df::DataFrames.DataFrame, row::Vector{Int64})
    @ DataFrames C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\DataFrames\BM4OQ\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:1680
  [3] top-level scope
    @ c:\Users\Shayan\Documents\PyJul Scripts\Jul-test.ipynb:2
  [4] eval
    @ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
  [5] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1196
  [6] #invokelatest#2
    @ .\essentials.jl:716 [inlined]
  [7] invokelatest
    @ .\essentials.jl:714 [inlined]
  [8] (::VSCodeServer.var"#164#165"{VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments, String})()
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\Shayan\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\serve_notebook.jl:19
  [9] withpath(f::VSCodeServer.var"#164#165"{VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments, String}, path::String)
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\Shayan\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\repl.jl:184
 [10] notebook_runcell_request(conn::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.JSONRPCEndpoint{Base.PipeEndpoint, Base.PipeEndpoint}, params::VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments)
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\Shayan\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\serve_notebook.jl:13
 [11] dispatch_msg(x::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.JSONRPCEndpoint{Base.PipeEndpoint, Base.PipeEndpoint}, dispatcher::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.MsgDispatcher, msg::Dict{String, Any})
    @ VSCodeServer.JSONRPC c:\Users\Shayan\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\JSONRPC\src\typed.jl:67
 [12] serve_notebook(pipename::String, outputchannel_logger::Base.CoreLogging.SimpleLogger; crashreporting_pipename::String)
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\Shayan\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\serve_notebook.jl:136
 [13] top-level scope
    @ c:\Users\Shayan\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.6.17\scripts\notebook\notebook.jl:32
 [14] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base .\Base.jl:418
 [15] exec_options(opts::Base.JLOptions)
    @ Base .\client.jl:292
 [16] _start()
    @ Base .\client.jl:495
```

Also, I tried `insert!(dataframe , vec)`, but I got this:

```
MethodError: no method matching insert!(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Vector{Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  insert!(!Matched::DataStructures.AVLTree{K}, ::K) where K at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\DataStructures\vSp4s\src\avl_tree.jl:128
  insert!(!Matched::DataStructures.SortedSet, ::Any) at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\DataStructures\vSp4s\src\sorted_set.jl:114
  insert!(!Matched::DataStructures.SortedDict{K, D, Ord}, ::Any, !Matched::Any) where {K, D, Ord<:Base.Order.Ordering} at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\DataStructures\vSp4s\src\sorted_dict.jl:268
```

How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

**Additional Note:** `vec` is not defined before `dataframe` and is intended! I mean, I have to create an empty DataFrame first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the following options depending what you need.

1. Add a vector without copying

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> df = DataFrame()
0×0 DataFrame

julia> df.x = x
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> df.x === x
true
```

or

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> df = DataFrame()
0×0 DataFrame

julia> df[!, :x] = x
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> df.x === x
true
```

2. Add a vector with copying

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> df = DataFrame()
0×0 DataFrame

julia> df[:, :x] = x
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> df.x == x
true

julia> df.x === x
false
```

3. If you have a scalar you can do (also works with vectors)

```
julia> df = DataFrame()
0×0 DataFrame

julia> insertcols!(df, :x => 1)
1×1 DataFrame
 Row │ x
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
```

Comment: For completeness' sake (since it's mentioned for the other two): in the case of `insertcols!`, whether the vector is copied depends on the `copycols` keyword argument - which defaults to `true` if unspecified.

Comment: Correct. I have skipped this kwarg not to overly complicate things, as I have given an example of passing a scalar (in which case allocation happens always).

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
julia> r=DataFrame(:a=>rand(5),:b=>rand(5))
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a         b        
     │ Float64   Float64  
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ 0.8613    0.207534
   2 │ 0.994096  0.561571
   3 │ 0.220975  0.429286
   4 │ 0.884805  0.835078
   5 │ 0.964035  0.653509

julia> r[:,:c]=rand(5)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.5722614445699863
 0.1582911302051686
 0.14114436033460553
 0.20981872218154363
 0.07636493031324465

julia> r
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a         b         c         
     │ Float64   Float64   Float64   
─────┼───────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.8613    0.207534  0.572261
   2 │ 0.994096  0.561571  0.158291
   3 │ 0.220975  0.429286  0.141144
   4 │ 0.884805  0.835078  0.209819
   5 │ 0.964035  0.653509  0.0763649
```

---

nb: also works starting from an empty dataframe:

```
julia> r=DataFrame()
0×0 DataFrame

julia> r[:,:c]=rand(5)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.6792303081607677
 0.08094072339097869
 0.5171831771259873
 0.35343166177619845
 0.44751700973394026

julia> r
5×1 DataFrame
 Row │ c         
     │ Float64   
─────┼───────────
   1 │ 0.67923
   2 │ 0.0809407
   3 │ 0.517183
   4 │ 0.353432
   5 │ 0.447517
```

---

> **Update & summary** (completed using Bogumił Kamiński answer)
>
> You can do:
>
> ```
> d[:,:colname] = x_vector # copy of x
> d[!,:colname] = x_vector # no copy of x (shared)
> ```
>
> if x is a scalar, see Bogumił Kamiński answer.

Comment: Please read my additional note! I have to create an empty DataFrame first of all. Because I don't have the `vec` at that moment. I have to start with an empty DataFrame. This is not the answer to my question.

Comment: @Shayan This also works starting from an empty dataframe